# BreadCrumb Implementation

Tags: java, e-commerce, breadcrumbs

I have a requirements of implementing breadcrumb in our J2EE application at both back-end and on user interface.
I only know what is breadcrumb but not aware of its other technical aspects as i have head that it also help in SEO and other things.

My question is what things one need to be take care while developing such functionality like one few approaches i can think of

1. Put user traversing path in the session and can use that to build breadcrumb.
2. Like in product detail page instead how user navigate show the path as 
   Catalogue->Category->Product.

Please suggest me what best approach one should have, also if any one can refer a sample implementation in Java for the breadcrumb that will be an added bonus for me to move ahead

Comment: Generally, breadcrumbs are used to show the hierarchical categorization of pages rather than the user's trail.

Comment: @That mean my second assumption is on right track..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research i found the suitable answer on web development.here is a link for the same
[Link for BreadCrumb](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/recommended-approach-for-implementing-breadcrumbs)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about technology you gonna use.
But there is breadcrumb add-on for Vaadin. You can find it in [addon-directory](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/lexaden-breadcrumb) and probably find some ideas for your project.